# Sort list by tokens with the least distance

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort a list of strings. I have 1000 addresses (some custom address data separated by spaces). The second thing is my search query. Now I want to get all the word tokens (without numbers) and sort them by the least distance.

e.g.

```
string query = "123 HAM";
// 1. get only "HAM" token
// 2. count distances
// 3. sort by them
//distance("HAM", "12 HAM DRIVE") -> 0
//distance("HAM", "13 HAM DRIVE") -> 0
//distance("HAM", "14 HAMER DRIVE") -> 2
//distance("HAM", "37 HAMMERSMITH AVENUE") -> 8
```

If my query token is `HAM`, then distance between `HAM` and `HAM` is 0, between `HAM` and `HAMER` is 2 (because `HAMER` has 2 letters more), etc.

I get 'word' tokens:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetLetterTokens(string location)
{
    string[] words = location.Split(new[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return words.Where(word => Regex.IsMatch(word.Trim(), @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"));
}
```

Now for each address I want to count these distances and sort by them. Is there any fast way to do that? I mean e.g. using `List<>.Sort`.

Thx for suggestions:)

Comment: Specify distance, i can see only strings. `"123 HAM"` means the distance for _"HAM"_ is `123 whatever`?

Comment: My distance is a difference in letters between token from the query and words containing that token in address string. If my query token is "HAM", then distance between HAM and HAM = 0, between HAM and HAMER = 2 (because HAMER has 2 letters more) etc.

[edit] My query can contain many different words, but I need to get only words (no numbers), then I need to find the word consisting of the token from my query (if token is "HAM" then all the words with "HAM" inside match), then I need to count distances and sort them:) Kinda strange, but it should look like this.

Comment: I think you can use [Levenshtein Distance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein)

Comment: Not exactly, because that algorithm counts distances between all the words, I need only get specific, but there is no problem, I just need to find a word containing my token and substract their legths. Problem is how to use it clever to write something comparer-like to sort it as fast as it's is possible. I thought about using Dictionary<string, int> (string - a word with token from address, int - distance). Maybe it's a better way. I get many queries with much data, so I need it to be fast:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
    string token = "HAM";
    List<string> addresses = new List<string>
    {
        "12 HAM DRIVE",
        "13 HAM DRIVE",
        "14 HAMER DRIVE",
        "37 HAMMERSMITH AVENUE",
        "15 HAM HAMER DRIVE",
    };

    var result = from a in addresses
                 let tokens = GetLetterTokens(a)
                 let distances = from t in tokens
                                 where t.Contains(token)
                                 select t.Length - token.Length
                 where distances.Any()
                 let distance = distances.Min()
                 orderby distance
                 select new
                 {
                     Address = a,
                     Distance = distance,
                 };
```

If you only want tokens that start with the token you look for use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for:D works great. Do you have any idea how to modify it a little? Instead of getting one token "HAM" I would have a list of tokens e.g. { "HAM", "ROAD", "AVEN" }. Now I want to sort by "HAM" in the first order, later received groups by "ROAD" (saying groups I mean groups with the same distance) and in the end by "AVEN". It would be everything I can do here.

Comment: Ok, nvm. I did it:) Thx for help.

Comment: Just one more question. Sometimes distance cannot be counted, because all the tokens could not contain our query token. How to skip these cases?

Comment: @Nickon I modified the query to remove addresses which do **not** contain the token.

Answer (score 2):

> I think you can use [Levenshtein Distance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein) – L.B

```
var result = addresses.OrderBy(a => 
         string.Join(" ", GetLetterTokens(a))
       , new LevenshteinDistance());

public class LevenshteinDistance : IComparer<String>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compute the distance between two strings.
    /// </summary>
    public int Compare(string s, string t)
    {
    int n = s.Length;
    int m = t.Length;
    int[,] d = new int[n + 1, m + 1];

    // Step 1
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return m;
    }

    if (m == 0)
    {
        return n;
    }

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; d[i, 0] = i++)
    {
    }

    for (int j = 0; j <= m; d[0, j] = j++)
    {
    }

    // Step 3
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        //Step 4
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++)
        {
        // Step 5
        int cost = (t[j - 1] == s[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

        // Step 6
        d[i, j] = Math.Min(
            Math.Min(d[i - 1, j] + 1, d[i, j - 1] + 1),
            d[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }
    // Step 7
    return d[n, m];
    }
}
```